# How can I estimate what will blow first - PTC/TVS protection combination or my IC

Tags: protection, tvs, ptc

I want to protect an IC output (MOSFET driver) that the vendor says can survive V_cc +0.3V on the output pin from an accidentially connected overvoltage of about 35V on the plug. Problem: my V_cc is only 5V!

One approach I found here at StackExchange EE was to use a combination of TVS and a PTC.

[image]

My assumption is, that the 35V will create a current trough the highside switch to V_cc of the MOSFET Driver or through the lowside switch to GND.

1) How will I know if the IC can survive the time that the PTC needs to become highly resistive? Can I look for hints in the IC datasheet?

2) I always thought TVS are meant for ESD or surge protection (short time and high voltages) and not for longer durations of moderate (35V) Voltages. Can they also be used for these things?

3) Whats a good starting point to understand these time related questions concerning PTC and TVS? Are there other solutions you can point me to? I have a bad market overview on what's available.

Comment: Usually the MOSFET driver has to be very close to the transistor, adding PTC to the output of the driver makes no sense since it will degrade the basic function of the driver.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič you are of course right. I need to mention, that I do not use the IC as a MOSFET driver. I use it only because of its capability to drive some capacitive load.

Comment: If you describe what is your intention, maybe some better solution could be found, like a galvanic separation, other mosfet switch totem pole with OC OV protection,...

Comment: How about reading the data sheet?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič My intention is to create an 5V trigger signal for a input that  capacitive load. To get a decent edge (in the oder of 200ns) For this task, I thought this IC type was fitting.

Comment: @Andyaka your answer sound pretty sarcastic, I guess it was not meant to be. From an beginner standpoint datasheets can sometimes be a hard way to understand concepts or to get into topics. Often Appnotes or similar papers are way more helpful. If you have problems identifying what you are lacking to understand you will often also have problems figuring it out in the datasheet.

Comment: OK then, how about supplying a link to the DS. How can you expect this question to attract good answers without a specific part. Also can you explain why the chip might receive over-voltages - we have no schematic to hint so again, this makes it unlikely to attract good answers. From specifics maybe your general questions can be answered and I'm saying this because requests for general info on non-specified devices tend to get closed. Read the rules on questions and yes I was being a bit sarcastic - I was hinting that only YOU have knowledge about the DS.

Comment: @Andyaka I have the ADP3624 in mind 
http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADP3623_3624_3625_3633_3634_3635.pdf

My estimation was that it is more dependent on the protection circuit then the IC, so I did not mention it, probably wrong as you stated.
The chip could receive overvoltage, because the output pins of the IC are accessable and I can't control if someone, by accident, connects external voltage supply (24-35V) to it. If this happens I want to make sure the IC survives. Function of course would not matter in that case until the over-voltage is removed.

Comment: The DS specifies that outputs can sink or source 4A. I read this as the device being able to sink 4A to the positive rail when it is forced high. Based on this it is possible to use an output resistor of maybe 0.22 ohms. This can be used as a crowbar sense protecting the output from currents in excess of 4A - a fuse could also be put in the output line should 4A be continued to be pushed into the device from the externally applied incorrect wire. I'm not making this an answer because you should speak to ADI about this. The DS is inadequate in this respect in my opinion.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for the hints. This is a solution that will most likely work. If I understand correctly, the crowbar mechanism will trigger once, and then would need replacement (the fuse part of the crowbar). Correct?
The 4A sink current from the DS makes me confident that the IC will not blow to easy but, as you mention, it does not cover the continuous application of the fault voltage.

I will try to see if the solution with a TVS in combination with a PPTC could work for my case, because this would be "self healing" so to speak. Maybe even some of the PolyZen devices are fitting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using normal PTC will give us a well predictable behavior. The thermal time constant given by datasheet is referred to zero-power conditions. Is behavior is determined by too much factors (ambient temperature, voltage applied, etc).

Why dont use a fuse? Maybe a resettable fuse (PPTC, I think you means this device in the question), that generally is little slow compared to fast-acting fuse, according to [Littlefuse specification](http://www.littelfuse.com/products/resettable-ptcs.aspx#option2) (see "Time-Current Characteristic").

<del>Or better, why not an **overvoltage crowbar**?</del>

> 3) Whats a good starting point to understand [...]

Some useful links about thermistors:

1. http://www.vishay.com/docs/33016/engnote.pdf
2. http://www.littelfuse.com/products/resettable-ptcs.aspx
3. http://www.avx.com/resources/technical-info-papers/circuit-protection-emi-filtering/
4. [AVX about PTC](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/dl/Datasheet-054/DSA0011569.pdf) (interesting for current-time characteristic)

And about TVS, Littlefuse and Vishay sites are a good sources of informations.

Comment: I deleted overvoltage crowbar because if I'm right the crowbar it is not so fast... There's anyone experienced about this that could confirm or deny?

Comment: thank you @Antonio for this information. I think I am getting closer to understand. So will the TVS need to clamp my error voltage down to V_cc +0.3V for the duration until the PPTC catches up and becomes high impedant?
I still have some work to do until I get behind it ^^

Comment: They even seem to make the 'resattable PTC with TVS'-solution as one part called PolyZen (by TE). http://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/t/te-connectivity/polyzen-ce

I'll try to figure out if this is what will solve my application. Still a lot of thermal considerations I have to catch up to. Thanks again for the hints!

Comment: @Villotron Yes. The only problem is the TVS act more fast than PPTC. Polyzen-ce? I'll go to read abuot this device. :-)